# What is the equivalent of blue screen of death in linux?

Tags: crash

Will the computer just freeze or will it display a error message like BSoD?

Answer (score 11):

Its called a kernel panic. Linux usually doesn't get kernel panic because it is very good at handling hardware (What led you to ask this question). In some cases Linux might get kernel panics if you have malfunctioning hardware. In such cases your system will cease to work, producing an error similar to below:

[image]

Comment: Not just hardware. Missing core files and terrible configurations can also cause kernel panics. So can drivers (`b43`, looking at you) and just running out of memory.

Comment: Widely covered in [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_of_death]

Comment: @KazWolfe Those Broadcam WiFi cards mostly do it.It also flashes the caps lock and scroll lock (if you PC has a light)

Comment: In some case, the GUI freezes and you can't switch to a console. The only clue you got if the **blinking LED of the CAPS lock** key telling you the kernel panicked.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you even got a **stack trace** like this example back in 2012 when I simply unplug my phone and got this crash:

[image: kernel panick with stack trace]